# Accessing all fields of first record selected as distinct record on the base of one column

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datatable, dataset

I want distinct records on the bases of one column. I use the following method.

```
dtUniqRecords = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, Columns);
```

But actually I want that one distinct record on the bases of that column I mention in `ToTable` method. I want that the first record which selected should show its other column values.

For example:

```
PkID Name Column1 Column2 ...
221  null null null
```

I want result to be like

```
221 test1   test2 test3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is something you could do that is similar for a datatable, but you could always cast it as a List and get the distinct values with a custom comparer

```
    var dt = new DataTable();
    var dataList = (from DataRow row in dt.Rows
                select new SomeObject
                {
                    Id = Convert.ToInt32(row["Id"])
                }).ToList();

    dataList = dataList.Distinct(new SomeDistinctComparer()).ToList();



    public class SomeObject
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeDistinctComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeObject>
    {
        public bool Equals(SomeObject x, SomeObject y)
        {
            return x.Id == y.Id;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(SomeObject obj)
        {
            return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```